# Filter MODIS data for particular sensor zenith angle using earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis

I need surface reflectance data with a sensor zenith angle <45 degrees. My current code for 
green ndvi is: I have selected the related surface reflectances and the sensor zenith angle layer. But I don't know how to filter for observations with the view angle<45. Can someone help with this please.

```
 var A = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MYD09GA"),

 var NIR = A.select('sur_refl_b02')
 var Green = A.select ('sur_refl_b04')
 var sza = A.select('SensorZenith')

var addGNDVI = function(image) {
var gndvi = ee.Image(image).normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b02', 'sur_refl_b04']).rename('G');
return ee.Image(image).addBands(gndvi);
}


//Map the GREENNDVI over collection A
var AGNDVI = A.map(addGNDVI)
var AGNDVIdated = AGNDVI.filterDate('2012-06-01','2014-09-30')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to mask each image as you're mapping over the collection with `image.select('SensorZenith').lt(4500)` as your mask. The `SensorZenith` band is `degrees * 100`:

```
var AGNDVI = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MYD09GA")
  .filterDate('2012-06-01', '2014-09-30')
  .map(addGNDVI)

Map.addLayer(AGNDVI.first(), {bands: 'G', palette: 'red,orange,yellow,green'}, 'G')
Map.addLayer(AGNDVI.first(), {bands: 'SensorZenith', min: 0, max: 4500}, 'SensorZenith')

function addGNDVI(image) {
  var gndvi = image
    .normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b02', 'sur_refl_b04'])
    .rename('G')
  return image
    .addBands(gndvi)
    .updateMask(
      image.select('SensorZenith').lt(4500)
    )
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/682b9cd791ef69c685d7238e87a45bc9

Comment: Hi Daniel. Thanks for your help. Can I just confirm, .lt(4500) implies that any pixels with greater than 4500 would be excluded from my analysis? right?

Comment: Almost - greater than *or equals* would be excluded.